# How to find minimum number of m?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, discrete-optimization

Let $N = \{1, 2,\ldots, n\}$. Let $\{A_1,A_2, \ldots, A_m\}$ be subsets of N and there union is N. What is the minimum value of m for which for any $Y\subseteq N$ ($Y\neq A_i$ for any i), there exists $A_i$ for some $i\in \{1,2, \ldots,m\}$ such that $|Y\cap A_i|=1$?

I found that $\{1,2\},\{3\}, \{4\}, \ldots, \{n\} $ is such a collection. So m=n-1 here. Is this the minimum?

Comment: I believe so, but it is not so simple.  Another that works is $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{5\},\{6\},\ldots,\{n\}$.  This also has $m=n-1$  You can't have more pairs than two or you need more sets with more elements and $m$ increases higher.